# Create a modal dialog in a Safari extension

Tags: javascript, safari-extension

I am creating an extension that captures some DOM elements and throws it in a form in a modal dialog. So far, I have been successful with Chrome and Firefox, but not with safari. What's the work around?

Comment: Is it the same API? http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: i am able to display the tab, but the modal dialog by definition means, user must do something with the modal dialog before the background page can do anything. I am not able to achieve that. As soon as i press the submit button on the forms, the popup is displayed, but the page in the background also processes. Also, the user is able to ignore the popup. That popup is vital part of my workflow, and i dont want it to be ignored.

Comment: Silly question, but do you return false/preventDefault the submit?